# How to Render a Enquery form in a product show page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I Have a product's show page which displays the information about the product. I also have an enquery form on the same show page, so the user can send an enquery regarding the product.The enquery data has to be saved into the `Enquery` model with a corresponding `EnqueresController` which should have `index` and `show` actions.

How can this be done in Rails?
Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in Advance!

```
@product =  Product.find(params[:id])
@enquery = Enquery.where("product_id = ?",@product.id).present?
```

Comment: can you add some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `app/controllers/products_controller.rb`

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController

  // initialize your enquiry model object here
  // since you are showing the form on show page

  def show
    @products = Products.all
    @enquiry  = Enquiry.new 
  end

end
```

after that in the show view at `show.html.erb`

```
<%= form_for @enquiry do %>
  <%= text_field :modelname, :attribute_name, options %>
  ....
  ....
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank for the Quick response.But I have to pass product_id along with the  enquery details into the Enquery model.

                  @enquery = Enquery.where("product_id =    ?",@product.id).present?

Comment: @SureshChipurupalli set a hidden field in the form called `product_id` and set your value there is one way to pass to the model